# I have 8 points in a point cloud data. How do I reconstruct points to form a cube of point cloud data?

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, 3d-reconstruction

Given the 8 corner points, I want to reconstruct them and fill up the cube full of point cloud data. Using Point Cloud Library, how can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "reconstruct"? Do you want to mesh them and then fill the cube with random points? Could you explain yourself better?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following, it's lengthy and just constructs the surface of the cube, some tweaking and you'll get what you want :

```
struct Dimensions // min and max points of cube 
{
float min_x, min_y, min_z, max_x, max_y, max_z;
}

PointCloudColoredPtr draw_box(Dimensions& dim, uint32_t rgb)
{
float step = 0.4;
PointCloudColoredPtr box(new PointCloudColored);
PointTColored point_min, point_max;
point_min.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);
point_max.rgb = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&rgb);

// add points according to X
point_min.x = dim.min_x;
point_max.x = dim.max_x;

float b1, b2;
for (b1 = dim.min_y; b1 < dim.max_y; b1 += step)
{
    for (b2 = dim.min_z; b2 < dim.max_z; b2 += step)
    {
        point_min.y = b1;   point_max.y = b1;
        point_min.z = b2;   point_max.z = b2;
        box->points.push_back(point_min);
        box->points.push_back(point_max);
    }
}

// add points according to Y
point_min.y = dim.min_y;
point_max.y = dim.max_y;

for (b1 = dim.min_x; b1 < dim.max_x; b1 += step)
{
    for (b2 = dim.min_z; b2 < dim.max_z; b2 += step)
    {
        point_min.x = b1;   point_max.x = b1;
        point_min.z = b2;   point_max.z = b2;
        box->points.push_back(point_min);
        box->points.push_back(point_max);
    }
}

// add points according to Z
point_min.z = dim.min_z;
point_max.z = dim.max_z;

for (b1 = dim.min_x; b1 < dim.max_x; b1 += step)
{
    for (b2 = dim.min_y; b2 < dim.max_y; b2 += step)
    {
        point_min.x = b1;   point_max.x = b1;
        point_min.y = b2;   point_max.y = b2;
        box->points.push_back(point_min);
        box->points.push_back(point_max);
    }
}

return box;
}
```